# Drop Duplicates in a DataFrame Keeping the Row with the Least Nulls

Tags: python, pandas

With this DataFrame:

```
d = {'A' : pd.Series(['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB','CC'], 
           index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']),
     'B' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['b', 'd','e']),
     'C' : pd.Series([4., 5., 6.], index=['b', 'd', '']),
     'D' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.,4.], index=['a', 'c', 'd','e'])}

In[1]: pd.DataFrame(d)

Out[1]: 
     A    B    C    D
 a  AA  NaN  NaN  1.0
 b  AA  1.0  4.0  NaN
 c  AA  NaN  NaN  2.0
 d  BB  2.0  5.0  3.0
 e  CC  3.0  6.0  4.0
```

I would like to drop duplicates on `df['A']` and keep the row with the fewest null values in the columns that are not being dropped `on`.

```
In[2]: pd.DataFrame(d).drop_duplicates(on='A', **magical_answer=True**)

Out[1]: 
     A    B    C    D
 b  AA  1.0  4.0  NaN
 d  BB  2.0  5.0  3.0
 e  CC  3.0  6.0  4.0
```

I can see a possible issue not enumerated in this example would occur if there are multiple rows with the fewest nulls, in that case it would be useful to have the `keep : {‘first’, ‘last’}` arg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have duplicated index, you can do:

```
df.loc[df.notnull().sum(1).groupby(df.A).idxmax()]

#    A    B   C   D
#b  AA  1.0 4.0 NaN
#d  BB  2.0 5.0 3.0
#e  CC  3.0 6.0 4.0
```

Comment: This is slick.  By default it keeps the first record if there are multiple rows with equal numbers of null values.  Thoughts on how to keep the last record?

Comment: You can reverse the two series, since `idxmax()` always get the first max index. `df.loc[df.count(1)[::-1].groupby(df.A[::-1]).idxmax()]`.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative would be to count the number of items in each row, sort the DataFrame and keep the last item so that it has the highest count.

```
(df.assign(counts=df.count(axis=1))
   .sort_values(['A', 'counts'])
   .drop_duplicates('A', keep='last')
   .drop('counts', axis=1))
Out: 
    A    B    C    D
b  AA  1.0  4.0  NaN
d  BB  2.0  5.0  3.0
e  CC  3.0  6.0  4.0
```

Comment: Nice solution. Also, vastly more efficient than the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try taking the advantage that `count` doesn't count NaN:

```
df_out = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[(x.count(axis=1)==x.count(axis=1).max())])
```

OR

```
df_out = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.count(axis=1).idxmax()])
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
      A    B    C    D
0 b  AA  1.0  4.0  NaN
1 d  BB  2.0  5.0  3.0
2 e  CC  3.0  6.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the values for all the columns, with `na_position='last'`. Then use the `drop_duplicate` function and use `keep='first'`

```
d_out = d.sort_values(by=list(d.columns),na_position='last').drop_duplicates('A',keep='first')
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
b   AA  1.0 4.0 NaN
d   BB  2.0 5.0 3.0
e   CC  3.0 NaN 4.0
```